# Experience Editor custom functionality

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, experience-editor

In some of our pages, we have a component that is a list of links. In Sitecore, this is stored in the following manner -

```
- Component data source
  - list item 1
  - list item 2
  - list item 3
```

Right now the Sitecore users can only add links to the list by going into the Content Editor and manually adding a list item. This is not very convenient for users as they have to constantly switch between Content and Experience Editor.

I would like to provide a functionality in the Experience Editor itself which can allow users to add these link items using a layover type functionality.

I did a quick search and wasn't able to find anything concrete. Is there a way to update achieve this functionality?

Comment: What about this one http://www.nonlinearcreations.com/Digital/how-we-think/articles/2014/03/Sitecore-Page-Editor-WebEdit-buttons.aspx ?

Comment: Thanks for the link. This is similar to what I'm looking for. If you add it as an answer, I'll give you some much deserved points.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should create a custom `WebEdit` button which will allow to add children to your datasource.

You can read more about it here [Sitecore Page Editor: Creating a WebEdit button](http://www.nonlinearcreations.com/Digital/how-we-think/articles/2014/03/Sitecore-Page-Editor-WebEdit-buttons.aspx)